# Using python to scrape a webpage and display the results to .html

Tags: python, html

I have created a script to display all present vacancies from a website. This works well and will print the list vertically via SSH.

However, what I now need to do is save this output as an unordered list and save it to a .html page.

The script I am using is:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://www.fasthosts.co.uk/careers/current-vacancies').text

tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

Vacancies = tree.xpath('//h1[@class="featuredvacancy__title featuredvacancy__title--invert grid-16 alpha"]/text()')

print Vacancies
```

This will print the output to screen.

However my other script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.fasthosts.co.uk/careers/current-vacancies'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

output = soup.find ('//h1[@class="featuredvacancy__title featuredvacancy__title--invert grid-16 alpha"]/text()')
text, link = output.text, output.get('vacancy.html')
```

Returns this error:

> File "test2.py", line 11, in 
>       text, link = output.text, output.get('vacancy.html')
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

I have now resolved saving the output to a .html file using the following script:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import urllib2

page = requests.get('https://www.fasthosts.co.uk/careers/current-vacancies')
content = html.fromstring(page.content)
Vacancies = content.xpath('//h1[@class="featuredvacancy__title featuredvacancy__title--invert grid-16 alpha"]/text()')

f = open('vacancy.html', 'w')
f.write(str(Vacancies))
f.close
```

Comment: Write your output to a file instead of SSH, save the file as .html

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved by saving the output to a `.html` file, using the following script:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import urllib2

page = requests.get('https://www.fasthosts.co.uk/careers/current-vacancies')
content = html.fromstring(page.content)
Vacancies = content.xpath('//h1[@class="featuredvacancy__title featuredvacancy__title--invert grid-16 alpha"]/text()')

f = open('vacancy.html', 'w')
f.write(str(Vacancies))
f.close
```

*Based on the [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8821548/klospros)'s edit to their post (and likely influenced by the comment of [@user3080953](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080953/user3080953))*.